# ABPersonVIewController at DidSelectRowAtIndex - method

Tags: iphone

i am trying to open ABPersonViewController at 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath:' method. But when i click on one of my record in table view it donot show anything.I am not able to configure out where is the problem. Where 'people' is array having contact name.
 here is my code:

```
 (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    pvc.personViewDelegate = self;
    pvc.displayedPerson = person;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
    [pvc autorelease];
}

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                    property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What is happening? Does the push take place to display an empty view. If no push is taking place, pls ensure that the viewcontroller has a navigationController

Comment: @7kv7: should i add navigation controller in IB or in my code...?

Comment: Thats up to you to decide. You can choose to have a navigation controller in ur IB to control the navigation or create one programmatically

Comment: @7kv7: can u show me how to do programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [`displayedProperties`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ABPersonViewController/displayedProperties). It is `NULL` by default.

For example,

```
     picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty]];
```

Comment: how to set displayedProperties?

Comment: You will have to create an array of properties selected from [`this page`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html). Go to the constants section and select all the property names that you need and create the array. Assign it to `displayedProperties`.